# Is there a "at some time in the future"?

Tags: phrase-usage, time

This might seem like a silly question, but is the following phrase correct:

> "... at some time in the future."

I am almost certain that "... at some point in the future." exists and there is ["... at some future time."](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/at+some+future+time), but the phrase "... at some time in the future." sound strange to my ears.

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=some+time+in+the+future%2Csome+point+in+the+future&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csome%20time%20in%20the%20future%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20point%20in%20the%20future%3B%2Cc0), while the more "metaphoric" *some **point** in the future* has indeed been gaining ground in recent decades, it's still much less common than *some **time** in the future*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the phrase "...at some point" is used as a substitute for "...at some future time". Both "..at some point in the future" and "...at some time in the future" are less common (and a bit redundant, since the future tense is already implied), but there's nothing wrong with either.